# How to obfuscate assets file in flutter builds

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, assets, obfuscation

After building an ipa or apk release with flutter I can easily track their assets by changing them into zip. Therefore anyone can access to the app assets. Is there any way to obfuscate or encrypt my assets files?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can't obfuscate plain-text files, which is why you don't store sensitive information in plain-text files that you bundle with your app. Encrypt them with an encryption tool (which Dart/Flutter does not provide), then decrypt them from within the app at runtime. (Or better yet, host them online securely somewhere and then fetch them at runtime.)